# remove duplicate information in .dat file (awk, sed)

Tags: awk, sed, header, duplicates

I have several large files which have been accidentally appended to with the correct information (i.e., the most recent data w/ header is correct, whereas the top information is incorrect), so there is a duplicate of the information:

```
H1 H2 H3 DATA SHIFT PROD VAL
12 12 13 8189 2 392 10
12 13 12 8199 3 281 11
...
...
H1 H2 H3 DATA SHIFT PROD VAL
12 12 13 8189 2 392 10
12 13 12 8199 3 281 15
...
...
```

If I only want to delete the header and information pertaining to the first header, how would I go about doing this? I can only get sed to work with matching 1 or 2 characters, and that deletes everything after, not before.

The expected output should simply be:

```
H1 H2 H3 DATA SHIFT PROD VAL
12 12 13 8189 2 392 10
12 13 12 8199 3 281 15
...
...
```

Comment: Could you please mention expected sample output in your post too and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0; next} $0==h{p++} p' file

H1 H2 H3 DATA SHIFT PROD VAL
12 12 13 8189 2 392 10
12 13 12 8199 3 281 15
...
...
```

record header, start printing after seeing the header again.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: thx, but in the future don't be too quick to accept an answer, this will discourage other responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution

```
$ perl -ne ' $x=$_ if $.==1; $y++ if $.>1 and $x eq $_; print if $y ' simpson.txt
H1 H2 H3 DATA SHIFT PROD VAL
12 12 13 8189 2 392 10
12 13 12 8199 3 281 15
...
...

$
```